# How to remove Java from RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse, product, rcp, xtext

I am making an Eclipse product which contains the Xtext plugin.I followed this tutorial https://kthoms.wordpress.com/2010/11/12/setting-up-a-rcp-product-for-a-dsl/ and I made a running product.

I created a platform runtime feature with the "needed" plugins. Most plugins are useless and I remove them one by one. But I can't remove Java from the RCP application and some others useless plugins.

When I tried to remove jdt, for example, Xtext doesn't work anymore.

How can I remove Java from the application? Is it implement by a plugin?

Thank you for your help guys :)

Comment: Eclipse platform required Java to run

Comment: But Is It possible to hide Java? For example in the project setting or in the perspective?

Comment: You can Check if there is an option in the plugin.xml that will not expose the plugins used.

Comment: In fact, I would like to remove java perspective.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove something from platform, you can use "activities".

Open your `plugin.xml`, `Extensions tab` then add the extension `org.eclipse.ui.activities`

Create an `activitypatternbinding` child as the extension, give it an ID of your choice, then fill the `pattern` attribute with the eclipse id of the element you want to hide. If you want to hide java perspective, this should be something like `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaPerspective`.

More infos [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/160373/) and [here](http://blog.vogella.com/2009/07/13/eclipse-activities/)

Comment: Thank your for your clear answer! I followed this tutorial https://kthoms.wordpress.com/2010/11/12/setting-up-a-rcp-product-for-a-dsl/ and I've a working Xtext RCP Application. What you said it's perfectly working :)

Comment: I'd hidden the useless perspective and now I am trying to do the same thing on menus and toolbar.

Do you know how can I hide Java Project from File-> New Project -> Java? I tried the pattern : org.eclipse.jdt.ui.java but it doesn't work...

Comment: try `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.JavaProjectWizard`